# Xquery parsing text with <a> tags

Tags: html, xml, xquery, html-parsing, html-content-extraction

I am using XQuery to extract content from html pages. The html body structure is of this kind:

```
 <td>
      <a href ="hw1">xyz </a>
          Hello world 1 
        <a href="hw2">Helloworld 2</a>
          Helloworld 3         
 </td>
```

My XQuery expression for extracting the text is as follows:

```
  //a[starts-with(@href,'hw1')]/following-sibling::text()
```

This expression gives me :

Helloworld 1  Helloworld 2 Helloworld 3

I would like to have it in this fashion:
Helloworld 1 Helloworld 2 Helloworld 3 or 
Helloworld 1  Helloworld 3

How do I specify to parse the text enclosed by  tags

Comment: I haven't done much with XQuery, so someone more knowledgeable will have to help with this.  However, you have a nested `a` tag, which is not allowed in HTML.  That may be part of the problem.

Comment: Is it also possible to get the output as 
Helloworld 1   <a href="hw2">Helloworld 2</a>   Helloworld 3

Comment: Oops I misplaced the </a> tag. Sorry for that.

 <td>
      <a href ="hw1">xyz</a>
          Hello world 1 
        <a href="hw2">Helloworld 2</a>
          Helloworld 3      
 </td>

Comment: You should edit your question, and supply the corrected HTML/XML.  This will make it easier for others to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear what you're looking for, but

```
let $content := 
 <td>
      <a href ="hw1">xyz </a>
          Hello world 1 
        <a href="hw2">Helloworld 2</a>
          Helloworld 3         
 </td>

return $content/text()
```

gives you the text nodes directly under the <td>. I don't see a difference between what you're getting and what you want... perhaps your post lost some formatting?